# Angular 2 --aot causes AnimationEntryMetadata failure

Tags: angular, typescript

My code works fine with `ng build` and `ng build --prod` howerver, when I add --aot to the command, it fails with the following error:

`Uncaught Error: Module build failed: Error: C:/Users/dremache/Code/control-f2/client/src/app/transitions.ts (11,14): Exported variable 'pageTransitions' has or is using name 'AnimationEntryMetadata' from external module "C:/Users/dremache/Code/control-f2/client/node_modules/@angular/core/src/animation/metadata" but cannot be named.)`

This is **transitions.ts**:

```
import { trigger,
  state,
  style,
  transition,
  animate,
  keyframes } from '@angular/core';


export const pageTransitions = 

  trigger('slideInOut', [

    state('in', style({transform: 'translateX(0)'})),

    transition('void => *', [
      style({transform: 'translateX(-60px)',opacity: '0'}),
      animate('300ms ease-out')
    ]),
    transition('* => void', [
      animate('300ms ease-out', style({transform: 'translateX(-60px)'}))
    ])
  ]);
```

This is the component that's importing it:

```
//other imports
import { pageTransitions } from './transitions';

@Component({
  //other properties
  animations: [ pageTransitions, 

      trigger('items', [
         // states and transitions here.. removing for cleanliness
      ]
  })
```

Any ideas?  I'm doing this to avoid re-defining the same animations.  These animations are being applied on components that are going from `void => *` to create page transition animations.

Answer (score 7):

Fixed it!

In my transitions.ts file I needed to change:

```
export const pageTransitions =
```

to:

```
export const pageTransitions: AnimationEntryMetadata =
```

(as well import `AnimationEntryMetadata` from `@angular/core`)

Comment: Nice, fyi for Angular 4+ it's now `AnimationTriggerMetadata`