# Angular2 angula-cli AOT support

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-aot

#### OS?

> Mac OSX Yosemite

#### Versions.

angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.21
node: 6.3.0
os: darwin x64

#### The log given by the failure. (have many of this)

> Exported variable 'slideInPartial' has or is using name 'AnimationEntryMetadata' from external module "/node_modules/@angular/core/src/animation/metadata" but cannot be named.)

#### Mention any other details that might be useful.

tsconfig.aot.json:

`{
  "declaration": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": false,
    "noImplicitUseStrict": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/unbundled-aot",
    "types": [
      "node",
      "jasmine"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "angular-cli/*": [ "./packages/angular-cli/*" ],
      "@angular-cli/ast-tools": [ "./packages/ast-tools/src" ],
      "@angular-cli/base-href-webpack": [ "./packages/base-href-webpack/src" ],
      "@ngtools/webpack": [ "./packages/webpack/src" ]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "packages/angular-cli/blueprints/*/files/**/*",
    "dist/**/*",
    "node_modules/**/*",
    "tmp/**/*"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "aot",
    "skipMetadataEmit": true
  }
}`

Execution command: 
`ng serve --aot -p src/tsconfig.aot.json`

Any changes in tsconfig.aot.json dose not affect anything.
Any Idea or help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue, when upgraded project with use of `angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.22-1`. I've simply added import of `AnimationEntryMetadata` from `@angular/core` to my animations file and it worked.

Some reading about your problem (which seems to be connected with `.d.ts` emitting):

- are you [duplicating](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40712656/1842492)?
- [Typescript errors when setting declaration to TRUE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35197360/1842492)
- TypeScirpt gurus track sth similar [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5711) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9944)